# Transform an array of integers into a string

Tags: c

A function returns an aray of integers and I want it to pass to another function which searches for some pattern. But the second function expects a string.

Example:

```
int IArray = {1, 2, 3};
// should be coverted into "123"
```

Is there a direct function available?  If not, how do I convert the array of integers into a string?

Comment: Looks like homework. There is no "direct function".  You need to write your own.  Show us your code so far for some constructive feedback.

Comment: No there isn't, and if there was it probably wouldn't do what you want (which isn't clear). Basically, you can't convert an array of integers of any values into an array of characters.

Comment: the  amount of text needing to write such a function is probably less then the amount of text in you question ;-)

Comment: Start with "convert one integer into string" and append the strings together...

Comment: To much important information is missing: 1) is the array compile-time sized or run-time sized, 2) are all the numbers guaranteed to be single-digit or not?

Comment: array is compile time and numbers represent percentage in whole number so will be [1,100].

Comment: So, `int IArray = {12, 3};` should be converted to `"123"` (same as for `{1, 2, 3}`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is no direct function to do that.

You'll have to use [sprintf](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/sprintf/).

Comment: And remember: sprintf returns the number of characters added to the array.

Comment: "have to" is a bit too strong I think.  The most obvious solution (to me) doesn't need `sprintf` at all.

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing in the C stdlib to do this, but it isn't hard to write the string manipulations:

```
#include <assert.h>

int transform_ints_to_string(int const* data, int data_length,
                             char* output, int output_length)
{
  // if not enough space was available, returns -1
  // otherwise returns the number of characters written to
  // output, not counting the additional null character

  // precondition: non-null pointers
  assert(data);
  assert(output);
  // precondition: valid data length
  assert(data_length >= 0);
  // precondition: output has room for null
  assert(output_length >= 1);

  int written = 0;
  for (; data_length; data_length--) {
    int length = snprintf(output, output_length, "%d", *data++);
    if (length >= output_length) {
      // not enough space
      return -1;
    }
    written += length;
    output += length;
    output_length -= length;
  }
  return written;
}
```

Example:

```
int main() {
  char buf[100] = "";
  int data[] = {1, 2, 3};
  if (transform_ints_to_string(data, 3, buf, sizeof buf) == -1) {
    puts("not enough room");
  }
  else {
    printf("%s\n", buf);
  }
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a direct function available I
>   can use?

NO

Answer (score 1):

most c and c++ compilers support [`itoa`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdlib/itoa/) function, which converts an int to a char*, or you can use sprintf to do this. The next thing is to concatenate all strings into a single string, you can use [`strcat`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstring/strcat/) . Follow the links, you will find examples for these two functions.

Answer (score 0):

If your `IArray` variable contains integer values in the range [0,9], then you can do something like this (pseudocode):

```
string := ""
While more numbers:
    string.append(next + '0')
```

In C, it is guaranteed that `'0'`, `'1'`, ..., `'9'` have consecutive integral values.

If this is not what you want, you need to define your problem more clearly.

Answer (score 0):

> int IArray = {1, 2, 3};

That's not C!

Do you mean;

int IArray[3] = {1, 2, 3};

You could do this...

```
for( loop = 0 ; loop < 3 ; loop++ )
  *(((char *) IArray)+loop) = '0' + IArray[loop];

*(((char *) IArray)+loop) = 0;

printf( "%s\n", (char *) IArray );
```

...but I wouldn't if I were you :-)

Comment: No worries, this wouldn't compile :-)